# How to Read values from xml file in java webservice and store them like application variables in Webservice?

Tags: java, xml, web-services

I am retrieving some values from xml file in web service. On Each call it goes to read xml file which makes it slow. I need to read them once and use same values on each request.
Can I store xml values as application variables like Asp.net? Also please share some best code snippet to read xml file in web-method.

## #

Webservice Code:-

```
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;



/**
 *
 * @author abc
 */
@WebService(serviceName = "TestXmlReader")
public class TestXmlReader {

    /**
     * This is a sample web service operation
     */
    int counts=1;
    @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
    public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {
        return "Hello " + txt + " !  "+counts;
        // for example Each time I get counts as 1....
        //so I need to increment it on each request from client
        ///I need to read xml file values here and store them as application variables 
        //so I dont have to read them from xml on each request

    }
}
```

## #

Client.jsp

```
    <%-- 
    Document   : index
    Created on : Feb 1, 2014, 10:23:28 AM
    Author     : abc
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <%-- start web service invocation --%><hr/>
    <%
    try {
    com.abc.TestXmlWebServiceClient.TestXmlReader_Service service = new com.abc.TestXmlWebServiceClient.TestXmlReader_Service();
    com.abc.TestXmlWebServiceClient.TestXmlReader port = service.getTestXmlReaderPort();
     // TODO initialize WS operation arguments here
    java.lang.String name = "Testing XML Service";
    // TODO process result here
    java.lang.String result = port.hello(name);
    out.println("Result = "+result);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    // TODO handle custom exceptions here
    }
    %>
    <%-- end web service invocation --%><hr/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both on client and server side you can create request/session/application scoped`EJB`s - insances of some class whitch would hold the data you need. For more information, as it is not a topic for single post, refer to [Java EE specificaton](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/home.htm)

Comment: I need to hold values in Webservice.. Like in init method or same. is there is any such method... Ok Let me explain in details.  I have one xml config file i need to get some values from it and hold it until webservice is restarted. meanwhile is xml values are changed webservice should be working with old stored values.

Comment: U can achieve this via EJB like i described. If this does not suit your needs, how about using some sort of simple cache ?

Comment: ok some how I solved it I am storing xml values into static class on first request and checking it on every request, if it becomes null then static class will be filled again. but is there any event i could fill that static class on web service startup?

Comment: That would be one approach, as long as all of your WS clients are ought to use same values (constants is suppose)

Comment: Thanks for your Help Really. and Yes all client gonna use same values. and i solved my problem using this great concept..  1) http://www.journaldev.com/1945/servlet-listener-example-servletcontextlistener-httpsessionlistener-and-servletrequestlistener...... 2) http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/what-is-listener-servletcontextlistener-example/